# Positivity property for scalar product on vector space with complex scalar field

Tags: real-analysis

I would just like to clear something up, If H is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, and $p:H\times H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a scalar product, then do we just ignore the positivity condition, $p(u,u) \geq 0$, since there is no order on the complex numbers?

Comment: By definition it would be $H \times H \to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for spotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $p(u,u) = \overline{p(u,u)}$ for any $u \in H$. So, $p(u,u) \in \mathbb{R}$ and we can require $p$ to fulfill $p(u,u) \geqslant 0$. According to Dirk Werner's book about functional analysis, we have the following definition:

> **Definition.** Let $X$ be a complex vector-space. A map $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle: X \times X \to F$ is called inner product or scalar product, if 
>   $$\langle x_1 + x_2,y\rangle = \langle x_1,y\rangle + \langle x_2,y\rangle$$
>   $$\langle \lambda x,y\rangle = \lambda\langle x,y\rangle$$
>   $$\langle x,y\rangle = \overline{\langle y,x\rangle}$$
>   $$\langle x,x\rangle \geqslant 0$$
>   $$\langle x,x\rangle = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = 0$$
>   for any $x,x_1,x_2,y \in X$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.